# Java Generics: Compiler won't infer types although they are compatible

Tags: java, generics, casting

I try to add an object of type `SubTest` to a list that has the generic type `T` which is defined as `<T extends SubTest>`. I expect this to work, but the compiler tells me that it can't convert `SubTest` to `T`. I just don't see the problem here.

Here is the full code:

```
public class Test<T extends Test.SubTest> {

    private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void add() {
        list.add(new SubTest()); //<- compile error here
    }

    protected static class SubTest {
    }

}
```

And yes, I know I could simply write

```
list.add((T) new SubTest());
```

and it would work. But the question is: why doesn't it work
without the unnecessary cast?

Comment: The underlying issue here is that `T` may be a _subtype_ of `SubTest`, in which case adding a `SubTest` to `list` would actively break type safety.  The cast isn't just necessary, it's likely to fail in reasonable cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type parameter `T` could be `SubTest`, but it could also be any potential subclass of `SubTest`.  If `T` is such a subclass, then you can't `add` a `SubTest` to `list`, because it's a superclass.

Because the compiler doesn't know which class `T` really is, it cannot allow you to pass a `SubTest` to `add`; it may violate type safety, which Java generics helps you maintain.

The cast to `T` will allow you to compile it, because a cast that may work tells the compiler, "I know what I'm doing, this will work".  However, this may result in a type safety violation as described above.  This may manifest itself in a `ClassCastException` at runtime, something like "cannot cast SubSubTest to SubTest" (if `T` were `SubSubTest`, a subclass of `SubTest`).

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct! Thanks. Just haven't seen it. I guess I should stop coding for today and get some sleep instead ;)

Comment: I'm trying to understand this as well. So `List<T>` is expected to be an homogeneous collection where all elements in the list are of the same type? But, if you declare `List<SubTest> list;`, then add() is free to add any object of a class that extends `SubTest` (including a `SubTest` object itself). In that case, the compiler is satisfied that all elements are of the same type (i.e., `SubTest`).

Answer (score 0):

Because `SubTest` is a *superclass* of `T`. When you declare a variable, `l`, to be of type `List<T>`, you are explicitly saying that the contents of `l` are at least of type `T`, and any client code should be able to perform all operations exposed by `T` on any item from the list. As `T` may be more specific than `SubTest`, you cannot add a `SubTest` instance to `l` as this instance won't necessarily obey to `T`'s contract.